# Adding Photos to Array and Displaying to UICollection View error

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**QUESTION**

**This code works to set an image to an array but comes up with the following error** - 2017-12-06 12:31:21.264812+0000 SmartReceipts[880:172369] [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

***I need to know what this means and if there is a possible fix around it?***

```
import UIKit

class GalleryController: UICollectionViewController,
                         UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                         UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var Receipts = [UIImage?]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()





        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        //self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print(info);
        let newReceipts = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        self.Receipts.append(newReceipts)

        print("Array Contains \(self.Receipts.count) Receipts")
        print(self.Receipts)
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        print("completedIfStatement")
        }







    @IBAction func getReceipts(_ sender: Any) {
        print("PlusButtonPressed")

        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        // 2
        let albumAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Album", style: .default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("PhotosOption")
            self.getFromReceipts()
        })
        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("CameraOption")
            self.getFromCamera()
        })

        //
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("Cancel")
        })


        // 4
        optionMenu.addAction(albumAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(cameraAction)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        // 5
        self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    func getFromReceipts() {

        print("GetFromReceipts")
        let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraPicker.delegate = self
        cameraPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        self.present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil )


    }

    func getFromCamera() {
        print("GetFromCamera")
        let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraPicker.delegate = self
        cameraPicker.sourceType = .camera

        self.present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil )

    }



    //Number of Views
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.Receipts.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtindexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Receipts, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? PhotoCell


        cell?.imageView.image = self.Receipts[indexPath.row]
        return cell!

    }

}
```

Comment: on which line the error occurs? can you set a breakpoint and check please.

Answer (score 0):

The error maybe comes from not requesting the authorization to load an photo from the camera or the photo library. So you need to request for authorization before opening the camera like:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrary/1620736-requestauthorization

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'r not requesting Photo/Camera authorizations.
You have to add the below keys to Info.plist.

Camera permission :

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string> ${PRODUCT_NAME} Camera Usage< </string>
```

For Photo Library, you will want this one to allow app user to browse the photo library.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Photo Usage</string>
```

And in you'r source code, to ask permission for the photo/camera you need to add this code (Swift 3):

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ 
       (newStatus) in 
         if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized { 
          /* do stuff here */ 
    } 
})
```

Comment: Completed it but still get the error, it asks for permission and when clicked on image it still comes through with that error??

Comment: you need to dismiss the photo picker at end of `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])`